# Cron script Exec format error

Tags: cron

My cron job/script fails.

I'm running mythbuntu 14.04.  With previous version of Mythbuntu I have a problem, any help would be greatly appreciated!

I set up `cron.daily` with:

```
$ ls -la /etc/cron.daily
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   183 May 12 18:00 mc2xmlUpdate

$ cat mc2xmlUpdate

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin;/home/username

# m h dom mon dow user  command
36 17   * * *   root   /home/username/mc2xml/update.sh
```

File `update.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh 

/home/username/mc2xml/mc2xml
/usr/bin/mythfilldatabase --refresh all --file --sourceid 1 --xmlfile /home/username/mc2xml/xmltv.xml

cp /home/username/mc2xml/xmltv.xml /media/sdc1/DataShare/
```

I'm getting a `Exec format error` when I run:

```
$ run-parts -v /etc/cron.daily
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/mc2xmlUpdate
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/cron.daily/mc2xmlUpdate: Exec format error
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/mc2xmlUpdate exited with return code 1
```

Comment: It looks like you're confusing `/etc/crontab` with the files in `/etc/cron.daily/` **run by** `/etc/crontab`. Aside from that, what are you expecting `~` to expand to when root runs the script?

Comment: @BobcatJoe So simply place update.sh into your `/etc/cron.daily` directory

Comment: Thanks, I see my issue was that I was using ~ instead of the full path.  I assume the ~ is the current user and cron runs as root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files in `cron.{daily,hourly,weekly...}` are not in the `crontab` format, but scripts or executables that are directly executed. Files in `cron.d` are in the `crontab` format. Either:

- Move `mc2xmlUpdate` to `/etc/cron.d`, or
- Copy/link `/home/username/mc2xml/update.sh` to `cron.daily`

Also, your `PATH` specification contains a `;` instead of a `:`.

Comment: Also you should have `#!/bin/sh` as the first line